# Delete data from the database with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am sort of new to the Laravel framework and I am building just a simple blog. I can create a blog, show a blog and show a overview of all blogs. Now I would like to delete a blog. So, I have created a delete button in my view with a route link which will pass also the id of the article. Then, in my routes file I specify a delete request and a controller method. In the method I find the id and try to delete the row with the id I specified in the route/view.

This doesn't work. Instead of activate the destroy/delete method it shows the article instead of deleting it and activates the show method instead of the delete method. Can somebody help me out, What do I wrong?

**View.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{route('nieuws.destroy', ['id' => $blog->id])}}" onclick="return confirm('Weet je dit zeker?')">
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('/aanvragen', 'aanvragenController@index')->name('aanvragen.index');

    Route::get('/logout' , 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    Route::get('/nieuws/toevoegen', 'blogController@create')->name('blogs.add');

    Route::post('/nieuws/store', 'blogController@store')->name('nieuws.store');

    Route::delete('/nieuws/{id}', 'blogController@destroy')->name('nieuws.destroy');

});

Route::get('/nieuws', 'blogController@index')->name('blogs.index');

Route::get('/nieuws/{blog}', 'blogController@show')->name('blogs.show');
```

**Controller methods**

Delete/Destroy

```
public function destroy($id) {

    $blog = Blog::find($id);

    $blog->delete();

    return redirect('/nieuws');

}
```

Show

```
public function show(Blog $blog) {

    dd('show');


    return view('blogs.show', compact('blog'));

}
```

Comment: @Gijsberts you might want to re-check kunal's answer. Allowing GET requests to change data in any way is bad practice and a security risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `delete()` route requires you to POST your data.

HTML forms only supports GET and POST, other methods like DELETE, PUT, etc are not supported, that's why Laravel uses the `_method` to spoof methods which are not supported by HTML forms.

You **do not** want use GET in these cases, since someone can send a user the url (http://yoursite.com/blog/delete/1) in an IM or via email. The user clicks and the blog is gone.

Define your route as it would be when using resource controllers, so:

```
Route::delete('/nieuws/{id}', 'blogController@destroy')->name('nieuws.destroy');
```

And either use a form with the delete method:

```
// apply some inline form styles
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('nieuws.destroy', [$blog->id]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Or do some javascript magic as the link SR_ posted in his comment on your OP.

---

One more thing, add some sort of validation in your destroy action. Right now when you provide a non-existing id or something else, you will get a 500 error, instead you want to have a 404.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);

    $blog->delete();

    return redirect('/nieuws');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to update your destroy function like:

```
public function destroy($id) {

    $blog = DB::table('blog')->where('id',$id)->delete();

    return redirect('/nieuws');

}
```

And update your view code like:

```
<a href="{{route('nieuws.destroy', [$blog->id])}}" onclick="return confirm('Weet je dit zeker?')">
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: unfortunately not, because thats not the problem I guess. The problem is that my controller shows the `@show` method instead of the `@destroy` method

Comment: @Gijsberts What is the result of blog in show method ?

Comment: Just the details of the blog with data from the database. For testing purpose I use now the datadump function to see if it activates the show method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Laravel but I made it work through this way:
(I use 'Article' as the model's name and the `resource` "method" in the route stands for a bunch of useful routes including the route you wrote)

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id){
        Article::find($id)->delete();
        //$article = Article::find($id);
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Successfully deleted!');
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('article','ArticleController');
```

However, I think the problem lies in the default definition of database's name of your model. Laravel will assume that you have a database named blogs since you have a model named "blog". Are you having the database's name right?

Comment: Yes. Thats not the problem, because I can also add blogs and show them. The problem is that the destroy route is conflicting with the show route. Instead of activate the destroy method it does activate the show method.

Comment: How about changing the view into this:
`<form action="{{ url('admin/blog/'.$blog->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">delete</button>
                            </form>`

Answer (score 0):

To use `DELETE` HTTP Verb, your form should consists of the `POST` method and settings the `method_field('DELETE')`

Example:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('xxx.destroy', $xxx->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```